# Haskell | How to convert list of numbers in CSV file to a list containing lists

Tags: haskell

Not particularly great with Haskell here. Just getting started with I/O with Haskell

I have a CSV file with a single column with numbers as follows:

[image]

I have a function that takes in the name of the file and prints out a single list containing lists for each line of the CSV of type:

```
    printList :: String -> IO ()
    printList nameOfinputFile = do
                                s <- readFile inp
                                ..................
                                ..................
                                ..................
                                print (splitList)
```

where splitList is the intended output and for the given CSV file example, and it's meant to look like:

```
[ [1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16],[17] ]
```

How can I implement this while preserving the type of my function?

Comment: What do you mean by "with a single column"?  Each line is a single quoted string like "1,2,3"?

Comment: @DavidFletcher yes that's exactly it. If the CSV file is opened in Excel, only Column A is occupied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on [Replit](https://replit.com):

```hs
import Data.List(lines)
import Distribution.Simple.Utils(unintersperse)

splitList :: String -> [[Int]]
splitList = map (map read . unintersperse ',') . lines
```

Comment: I think that will produce something of type [String], but not [[Int]]

Comment: @FrancisKing. Now it's fixed, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There are likely to be many ways of doing the same thing. This is my version:

```
import Data.List.Split

convList [] = []
convList [""] = []
convList xs = map (\x -> read x :: Int) xs

main = do
    content <- readFile "Test.csv"
    let valuesStr = map (splitOn ",") $ lines content
    let valuesInt = map convList valuesStr

    print valuesInt
```

The main function uses `readFile` to slurp in the CSV file. The function `lines` is used to split the content, and then `splitOn` is mapped over the lines. Finally, a new function `convList` is mapped over the values inside each list. The function `convList` has three possibilities:

- Empty list, yields an empty list
- Blank line, yields an empty list
- Elements exist, yields values (here Int, could be Double)

Result with extra blank line:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16],[17],[]]
```